# Docker cloud automated build fails almost instantly

Tags: node.js, docker, build, dockerfile, docker-image

The automated build running on my personal docker cloud account fails within about 2 seconds of being triggered (manually and automatic from a git commit).

When i navigate into the failed build - the build logs window is stuck on 'Waiting for logs...' the Dockerfile tab also says 'Dockerfile is not available' but there is a dockerfile in my git repo.

Dockerfile:

```
$FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are 
copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4444
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

I have tried deleting and re-creating the automated build and also re-linking the git account to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is automated build is running where the Dockerfile isn't available. make sure Dockerfile is locate in root of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Yes the Dockerfile is in the root directory in the code repository (Bitbucket)

Comment: are you using bit bucket pipeline to build the image? if yes what is it?

Comment: Docker cloud is building the image, i do not have a Bitbucket pipeline setup.

Comment: I have ended up using Bitbucket pipelines to build the docker image and push into docker cloud, thanks Dasun.